# What is this plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I really like this plant--I'm just wondering what its name is (perhaps genus+species). I think this plant grows in the tropical rainforest in Malaysia.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: To me it looks similar to a young Banana plant ([Musa sp.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musa_%28genus%29)). The genus is native to south east asia, and there are many wild species.

Comment: I agree, this looks a lot like the banana plant.

Comment: Reposted as answer. Hopefully a botanist can chime in later. @biogirl

Comment: @masoug the stem of the banana plant is peculiar. If you could upload the picture of your plant's stem, it would be helpful

Comment: If it is a banana plant; then its trunk(invisible in this photo) is not actually stem. The actual stem stays underground.  the trunk is actually the leaf-bases sheathing around. The stem comes-out in the form of "scape" (a sort of inflorescence stick) at a season. (quite-lin a manner of onion-scape); which contains the banana -inflorescence on its top.

Comment: any info. about its size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no botanist, but this looks very similar to a young banana plant ([Musa sp.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musa_%28genus%29)) to me. The genus is native to south east asia, and there are many wild species. There are also a couple of other similarly looking genera in the banana family ([Musaceae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musaceae)).

Reasons why I'm thinking banana: the plant has tongue-shaped leafs with fairly short petioles, and the leaves have clear horizontal, unbranched veins and horizontal tears (common on banana plants). The leaves come from a single apical meristem and are scattered (not in e.g. distinct rows). Banana plants also have pseudostems, made out of packed leaf sheaths, but the stem cannot be seen in your picture. [Here](http://www.promusa.org/tiki-index.php?page=Morphology+of+banana+plant) is a webpage on banana morphology, if you want to get some further information.

Some examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not botanist either, but I think you are right--the  pattern of the leaves/stem matches the banana plant. Thanks!